# SQL error when I run this SQL to fetch WooCommerce Products

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

When I run your code above I get the above error message. I am just getting started with Woocommerce and SQL.

Do I need to do something specific to get this query to run in phpMyAdmin?

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p.guid, p.post_type, m.meta_key, m.meta_value, meta_sp.meta_value as sale_price, meta_ap.meta_value as additional_price
 FROM wp_posts p
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_sp ON p.id=meta_sp.post_id
 AND meta_sp.meta_key='sale_price'
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_ap ON p.id=meta_ap.post_id
 AND meta_ap.meta_key='additional_price'
 WHERE p.id=m.post_id
 AND m.meta_key='_rentable' AND m.meta_value='yes'";
```

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p.guid, p.post_type, m.meta_key, m.meta_value' at line 1

Comment: If you're using PHPMyAdmin interface, you shouldn't use a variable, just the query.  Take out the $sql = " and the ending ";

Comment: prob better to use wp query, it has meta query built in

Comment: wp query? what did you mean by that David? Could explain more please?

Comment: interesting how it return me: 
 "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0017 sec)"
Can't understand where the error is